# Сторонний сервер возвращает некорректную кодировку

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, phantomjs

```
<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">��������tT]��H�+��QAQ�7DTfU���l6l%��t7�en��o��}���&gt;�tU�S��p&amp;^�U��RW_�5�,I�Pʄ *Ib��O�Wr�d��-�I��`�Ml?�N!�G%5�*����%a�`��[A�Xm���8�x�  9禍�$nWYB��PO��2�
d����+w
�"��3���#��h�9+�A%��qnUS�u�zP��tҥ�q.�JҌ������x
���L0~c&amp;�(��]v�Bv�x��RqbǦ83J�c���܄��,�J��`��`Syq�   m�w:���d9�4`,�A@���f�������sbL1'C�9EC�
'S�Tgdւ��CA�d6]�qO0`G'kQv�z&amp;Cm�(������z�U�e��|SJ������4�}�ے���E�&gt;յ��,���f���?L�ˎ����P�˄�*)�G��&gt;���D�P!m�ObնD�Ƶ��Q���QW�� ^gm��بR&lt;pp��u�8��|���ш�!���K�W�n��:E�q��:�(���|����m��x0����HL:���&lt;H�Y&lt;Ngs�������p3�����7V;������1N%�X���f���g#�H���/Si��9OQ�%�k`ÙfLtT��p:1uC%���h��a`I�qkx��h��L���ÕS����E� @�Uq��wQ�B"��Ȫ�%���[*�5��꼠/�@iO�X�S��@Y;�hځ�;�g!s\�u����'���Za����q�%��=R��������g�z��~�Ͽ:�����ʏцW�T������/�{�Δ�LtJ�����؇��ѺV?��!��]�N���γ��g�-�]���I��k���
������,~����~�{n�Kj��ݝ7���|b�f&amp;j����?�������x/j ��</pre></body></html>
```

Как правильно составить заголовки чтобы ответ был корректным?
Источник данных: `https://www.copart.com/public/data/lotdetails/solr/43920307`, гет запрос.

Мои текущие заголовки:

```
page.customHeaders = {
    'accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,so;q=0.2',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
};
```

Comment: Спрашивайте у администратора этого стороннего сервера

Comment: @andreymal такой вариант не подходит. как это можно решить самостоятельно? понять как раскодировать это в читаемый вид будет для меня достаточно. спасибо

Comment: Во-первых, не зная, что за сервер, мы не сможем помочь. Во-вторых, не зная, что вы ожидаете, мы не сможем помочь. В-третьих, вопросы должны быть самодостаточными и воспроизводимыми, а ваш вопрос зависит от какого-то непонятного стороннего сервера, так что на stackoverflow это, похоже, оффтопик

Comment: переформулировал вопрос

Comment: Чтобы понять, что это за "кодировка", нужно знать точный источник данных и ваш текущий способ их обработки, так что всё написанное мной выше по-прежнему актуально :)

Comment: оу, спасибо. мне не хватает опыта чтобы ориентироваться что в этих вопросах важно, а что нет. спасибо за замечания. обновил вопрос.

Comment: Судя по всему, это что-то однобайтное (Windows-1251?), интерпритированное как UTF8. Пропишите в `<head>` мета-тег `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">`/

Comment: А где вы нашли API копарта? Можете поделиться информацией?

Comment: @OlegKovalyk могу продать готовый работающий парсер)